# Python if this and this and this

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to Python. I am writing a string function to check if a certain string contains certain multiple values. Is there a syntax in python to allow me to do something like this:

```
def strParse(str):
    a = 't'
    b = 'br'
    c = 'ht'
    if a in str AND b in str AND c in str:
        print('Ok!')
```

(The part I am unsure about is having multiple if statements on line.) Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost correct, just make the `and` lower-case:

```
def strParse(str):
    a = 't'
    b = 'br'
    c = 'ht'
    if a in str and b in str and c in str:
        print('Ok!')
```

Doesn't cause problems in this case, but you should avoid using variable-names that are also [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) (`str` is a builtin function/type)

If you have more values, you can do the same thing more tidily like so:

```
values = ['t', 'br', 'ht']
if all(x in instr for x in values):
    print("Ok!")
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try typing this into the Python REPL? What you're trying to do is perfectly valid in python, except the `and` keyword is lowercase, not uppercase.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks! I only put in upper case to ensure that you would understand it was that part I was not sure about. I am not familiar with the REPL, what is that?

Comment: REPL stands for read eval print loop. It is what you get when you invoke `python` with no arguments.

Answer (score 5):

```
if all(s in text for s in (a, b, c)):
   print("ok")
```